# VideoCapture is not working in OpenCV 2.4.2

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, video-capture, video-codecs

I recently installed OpenCV 2.4.2 in Ubuntu 12.04.

```
cap = VideoCapture(0)
```

is working. but I can't grab frames from some video source.

```
cap = VideoCapture("input.avi")
img = cap.read()
```

gives me a numpy with all zero elements.

I have also installed ffmpeg 0.11, Latest snapshot of x264, v4l-0.8.8 (All are latest stable versions)

```
cmake -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF WITH_V4L=ON .. 
make
sudo make install
```

When I do cmake, I get this

> -- Detected version of GNU GCC: 46 (406)
>   -- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/libIlmImf.so
>   -- Looking for linux/videodev.h
>   -- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
>   -- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
>   -- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
>   -- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
>   -- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
>   -- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
>   -- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
>   -- checking for module 'tbb'
>   --   package 'tbb' not found

And

```
--   Video I/O:  
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO  
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.0)  
--     FFMPEG:                      YES  
--       codec:                     YES (ver 54.23.100)  
--       format:                    YES (ver 54.6.100)  
--       util:                      YES (ver 51.54.100)  
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 2.1.100)  
--       gentoo-style:              YES  
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)  
--       app:                       YES (ver 0.10.36)  
--       video:                     YES (ver 0.10.36)  
--     OpenNI:                      NO  
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO  
--     PvAPI:                       NO  
--     UniCap:                      NO  
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO  
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l (ver 0.8.8)  
--     XIMEA:                       NO  
--     Xine:                        NO
```

I looked for videodev.h, etc

- /usr/include/linux/videodev2.h exists
- /usr/include/libavformat/avformat.h exists
- /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h exists

But I couldn't find `ffmpeg/avformat.h`

What's the problem here?

Comment: I also have a problem with videoCapture, it crashes when trying to open video...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So, I realized there was some problem with ffmpeg. and I rebuilt and installed ffmpeg and then changed flags for cmake to make opencv.

For ffmpeg,

```
 ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab 
make 
sudo make install
```

For OpenCV,

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ..
make
sudo make install
```

Here's the complete script to install OpenCV 2.4.2 https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV/blob/master/Ubuntu/2.4/opencv2_4_2.sh

and here's my blogpost about OpenCV 2.4.2 installation in detail http://jayrambhia.com/blog/install-opencv-2-4-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Comment: I simply don't understand how can they make it so complicated, this should be by default

Comment: What if I install everything via apt-get? Do you think I can get it running?

Comment: I guess it could be some license issue that must do it by this way.

Answer (score 0):

To run a full installation of OpenCV try the following:

`sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv`

For more details check out the following link http://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/