# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (vc_.isOpened()) in reset

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I've taken example code super_resolution.cpp. For creating good quality image from video source. So here code of super_resolution.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/superres/superres.hpp"
#include "opencv2/superres/optical_flow.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"

#if defined(HAVE_OPENCV_OCL)
#include "opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp"
#endif

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::superres;
bool useOclChanged;
#define MEASURE_TIME(op) \
    { \
        TickMeter tm; \
        tm.start(); \
        op; \
        tm.stop(); \
        cout << tm.getTimeSec() << " sec" << endl; \
    }

static Ptr<DenseOpticalFlowExt> createOptFlow(const string& name, bool useGpu)
{
    if (name == "farneback")
    {
        if (useGpu)
            return createOptFlow_Farneback_GPU();
        else
            return createOptFlow_Farneback();
    }
    else if (name == "simple")
        return createOptFlow_Simple();
    else if (name == "tvl1")
    {
        if (useGpu)
            return createOptFlow_DualTVL1_GPU();
        else
            return createOptFlow_DualTVL1();
    }
    else if (name == "brox")
        return createOptFlow_Brox_GPU();
    else if (name == "pyrlk")
        return createOptFlow_PyrLK_GPU();
    else
    {
        cerr << "Incorrect Optical Flow algorithm - " << name << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}
#if defined(HAVE_OPENCV_OCL)
static Ptr<DenseOpticalFlowExt> createOptFlow(const string& name)
{
    if (name == "farneback")
    {
        return createOptFlow_Farneback_OCL();
    }
    else if (name == "simple")
    {
        useOclChanged = true;
        std::cout<<"simple on OpenCL has not been implemented. Use CPU instead!\n";
        return createOptFlow_Simple();
    }
    else if (name == "tvl1")
        return createOptFlow_DualTVL1_OCL();
    else if (name == "brox")
    {
        std::cout<<"brox has not been implemented!\n";
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (name == "pyrlk")
        return createOptFlow_PyrLK_OCL();
    else
    {
        cerr << "Incorrect Optical Flow algorithm - " << name << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
#endif
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    useOclChanged = false;
    CommandLineParser cmd(argc, argv,
        "{ v   | video      |           | Input video }"
        "{ o   | output     |           | Output video }"
        "{ s   | scale      | 4         | Scale factor }"
        "{ i   | iterations | 180       | Iteration count }"
        "{ t   | temporal   | 4         | Radius of the temporal search area }"
        "{ f   | flow       | farneback | Optical flow algorithm (farneback, simple, tvl1, brox, pyrlk) }"
        "{ g   | gpu        |           | CPU as default device, cuda for CUDA and ocl for OpenCL }"
        "{ h   | help       | false     | Print help message }"
    );

    if (cmd.get<bool>("help"))
    {
        cout << "This sample demonstrates Super Resolution algorithms for video sequence" << endl;
        cmd.printParams();
        return 0;
    }

    const string inputVideoName = cmd.get<string>("video");
    const string outputVideoName = cmd.get<string>("output");
    const int scale = cmd.get<int>("scale");
    const int iterations = cmd.get<int>("iterations");
    const int temporalAreaRadius = cmd.get<int>("temporal");
    const string optFlow = cmd.get<string>("flow");
    string gpuOption = cmd.get<string>("gpu");

    std::transform(gpuOption.begin(), gpuOption.end(), gpuOption.begin(), ::tolower);

    bool useCuda = false;
    bool useOcl = false;

    if(gpuOption.compare("ocl") == 0)
        useOcl = true;
    else if(gpuOption.compare("cuda") == 0)
        useCuda = true;

#ifndef HAVE_OPENCV_OCL
    if(useOcl)
    {
        {
            cout<<"OPENCL is not compiled\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }
#endif
#if defined(HAVE_OPENCV_OCL)
    if(useCuda)
    {
        CV_Assert(!useOcl);
    }
#endif
    Ptr<SuperResolution> superRes;


#if defined(HAVE_OPENCV_OCL)
    if(useOcl)
    {
        Ptr<DenseOpticalFlowExt> of = createOptFlow(optFlow);
        if (of.empty())
            exit(-1);
        if(useOclChanged)
        {
            superRes = createSuperResolution_BTVL1();
            useOcl = !useOcl;
        }else
            superRes = createSuperResolution_BTVL1_OCL();
        superRes->set("opticalFlow", of);
    }
    else
#endif
    {
        if (useCuda)
            superRes = createSuperResolution_BTVL1_GPU();
        else
            superRes = createSuperResolution_BTVL1();

        Ptr<DenseOpticalFlowExt> of = createOptFlow(optFlow, useCuda);

        if (of.empty())
            exit(-1);
        superRes->set("opticalFlow", of);
    }

    superRes->set("scale", scale);
    superRes->set("iterations", iterations);
    superRes->set("temporalAreaRadius", temporalAreaRadius);

    Ptr<FrameSource> frameSource;
    if (useCuda)
    {
        // Try to use gpu Video Decoding
        try
        {
            frameSource = createFrameSource_Video_GPU(inputVideoName);
            Mat frame;
            frameSource->nextFrame(frame);
        }
        catch (const cv::Exception&)
        {
            frameSource.release();
        }
    }
    if (frameSource.empty())
        frameSource = createFrameSource_Video(inputVideoName);

    // skip first frame, it is usually corrupted
    {
        Mat frame;
        frameSource->nextFrame(frame);
        cout << "Input           : " << inputVideoName << " " << frame.size() << endl;
        cout << "Scale factor    : " << scale << endl;
        cout << "Iterations      : " << iterations << endl;
        cout << "Temporal radius : " << temporalAreaRadius << endl;
        cout << "Optical Flow    : " << optFlow << endl;
#if defined(HAVE_OPENCV_OCL)
        cout << "Mode            : " << (useCuda ? "CUDA" : useOcl? "OpenCL" : "CPU") << endl;
#else
        cout << "Mode            : " << (useCuda ? "CUDA" : "CPU") << endl;
#endif
    }

    superRes->setInput(frameSource);

    VideoWriter writer;

    for (int i = 0;; ++i)
    {
        cout << '[' << setw(3) << i << "] : ";
        Mat result;

#if defined(HAVE_OPENCV_OCL)
        cv::ocl::oclMat result_;

        if(useOcl)
        {
            MEASURE_TIME(
            {
                superRes->nextFrame(result_);
                ocl::finish();
            });
        }
        else
#endif
        {
            MEASURE_TIME(superRes->nextFrame(result));
        }

#ifdef HAVE_OPENCV_OCL
        if(useOcl)
        {
            if(!result_.empty())
            {
                result_.download(result);
            }
        }
#endif
        if (result.empty())
            break;

        imshow("Super Resolution", result);

        if (waitKey(1000) > 0)
            break;

        if (!outputVideoName.empty())
        {
            if (!writer.isOpened())
                writer.open(outputVideoName, CV_FOURCC('X', 'V', 'I', 'D'), 25.0, result.size());
            writer << result;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've compiled them. But when running in terminal.

```
./SuperResolution -v /home/raiym/Downloads/bird.avi
```

program gives error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (vc_.isOpened()) in reset, file /home/raiym/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/modules/superres/src/frame_source.cpp, line 161
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/raiym/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/modules/superres/src/frame_source.cpp:161: error: (-215) vc_.isOpened() in function reset

Aborted (core dumped)
```

frame_source.cpp is:

```
/*M///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  IMPORTANT: READ BEFORE DOWNLOADING, COPYING, INSTALLING OR USING.
//
//  By downloading, copying, installing or using the software you agree to this license.
//  If you do not agree to this license, do not download, install,
//  copy or use the software.
//
//
//                           License Agreement
//                For Open Source Computer Vision Library
//
// Copyright (C) 2000-2008, Intel Corporation, all rights reserved.
// Copyright (C) 2009, Willow Garage Inc., all rights reserved.
// Third party copyrights are property of their respective owners.
//
// Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
// are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
//
//   * Redistribution's of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
//     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
//
//   * Redistribution's in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
//     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
//     and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
//
//   * The name of the copyright holders may not be used to endorse or promote products
//     derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
//
// This software is provided by the copyright holders and contributors "as is" and
// any express or implied warranties, including, but not limited to, the implied
// warranties of merchantability and fitness for a particular purpose are disclaimed.
// In no event shall the Intel Corporation or contributors be liable for any direct,
// indirect, incidental, special, exemplary, or consequential damages
// (including, but not limited to, procurement of substitute goods or services;
// loss of use, data, or profits; or business interruption) however caused
// and on any theory of liability, whether in contract, strict liability,
// or tort (including negligence or otherwise) arising in any way out of
// the use of this software, even if advised of the possibility of such damage.
//
//M*/
#include "precomp.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::gpu;
using namespace cv::superres;
using namespace cv::superres::detail;

cv::superres::FrameSource::~FrameSource()
{
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// EmptyFrameSource

namespace
{
    class EmptyFrameSource : public FrameSource
    {
    public:
        void nextFrame(OutputArray frame);
        void reset();
    };

    void EmptyFrameSource::nextFrame(OutputArray frame)
    {
        frame.release();
    }

    void EmptyFrameSource::reset()
    {
    }
}

Ptr<FrameSource> cv::superres::createFrameSource_Empty()
{
    return new EmptyFrameSource;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// VideoFrameSource & CameraFrameSource

#ifndef HAVE_OPENCV_HIGHGUI

Ptr<FrameSource> cv::superres::createFrameSource_Video(const string& fileName)
{
    (void) fileName;
    CV_Error(CV_StsNotImplemented, "The called functionality is disabled for current build or platform");
    return Ptr<FrameSource>();
}

Ptr<FrameSource> cv::superres::createFrameSource_Camera(int deviceId)
{
    (void) deviceId;
    CV_Error(CV_StsNotImplemented, "The called functionality is disabled for current build or platform");
    return Ptr<FrameSource>();
}

#else // HAVE_OPENCV_HIGHGUI

namespace
{
    class CaptureFrameSource : public FrameSource
    {
    public:
        void nextFrame(OutputArray frame);

    protected:
        VideoCapture vc_;

    private:
        Mat frame_;
    };

    void CaptureFrameSource::nextFrame(OutputArray _frame)
    {
        if (_frame.kind() == _InputArray::MAT)
        {
            vc_ >> _frame.getMatRef();
        }
        else if(_frame.kind() == _InputArray::GPU_MAT)
        {
            vc_ >> frame_;
            arrCopy(frame_, _frame);
        }
        else if(_frame.kind() == _InputArray::OCL_MAT)
        {
            vc_ >> frame_;
            if(!frame_.empty())
            {
                arrCopy(frame_, _frame);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //should never get here
        }
    }

    class VideoFrameSource : public CaptureFrameSource
    {
    public:
        VideoFrameSource(const string& fileName);

        void reset();

    private:
        string fileName_;
    };

    VideoFrameSource::VideoFrameSource(const string& fileName) : fileName_(fileName)
    {
        reset();
    }

    void VideoFrameSource::reset()
    {
        vc_.release();
        vc_.open(fileName_);
        CV_Assert( vc_.isOpened() );
    }

    class CameraFrameSource : public CaptureFrameSource
    {
    public:
        CameraFrameSource(int deviceId);

        void reset();

    private:
        int deviceId_;
    };

    CameraFrameSource::CameraFrameSource(int deviceId) : deviceId_(deviceId)
    {
        reset();
    }

    void CameraFrameSource::reset()
    {
        vc_.release();
        vc_.open(deviceId_);
        CV_Assert( vc_.isOpened() );
    }
}

Ptr<FrameSource> cv::superres::createFrameSource_Video(const string& fileName)
{
    return new VideoFrameSource(fileName);
}

Ptr<FrameSource> cv::superres::createFrameSource_Camera(int deviceId)
{
    return new CameraFrameSource(deviceId);
}

#endif // HAVE_OPENCV_HIGHGUI

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// VideoFrameSource_GPU

#if !defined(HAVE_OPENCV_GPU) || defined(DYNAMIC_CUDA_SUPPORT)

Ptr<FrameSource> cv::superres::createFrameSource_Video_GPU(const string& fileName)
{
    (void) fileName;
    CV_Error(CV_StsNotImplemented, "The called functionality is disabled for current build or platform");
    return Ptr<FrameSource>();
}

#else // HAVE_OPENCV_GPU

namespace
{
    class VideoFrameSource_GPU : public FrameSource
    {
    public:
        VideoFrameSource_GPU(const string& fileName);

        void nextFrame(OutputArray frame);
        void reset();

    private:
        string fileName_;
        VideoReader_GPU reader_;
        GpuMat frame_;
    };

    VideoFrameSource_GPU::VideoFrameSource_GPU(const string& fileName) : fileName_(fileName)
    {
        reset();
    }

    void VideoFrameSource_GPU::nextFrame(OutputArray _frame)
    {
        if (_frame.kind() == _InputArray::GPU_MAT)
        {
            bool res = reader_.read(_frame.getGpuMatRef());
            if (!res)
                _frame.release();
        }
        else
        {
            bool res = reader_.read(frame_);
            if (!res)
                _frame.release();
            else
                arrCopy(frame_, _frame);
        }
    }

    void VideoFrameSource_GPU::reset()
    {
        reader_.close();
        reader_.open(fileName_);
        CV_Assert( reader_.isOpened() );
    }
}

Ptr<FrameSource> cv::superres::createFrameSource_Video_GPU(const string& fileName)
{
    return new VideoFrameSource(fileName);
}

#endif // HAVE_OPENCV_GPU
```

And  this code is where error found in frame_source.cpp (line 161):

```
void VideoFrameSource::reset()
{
    vc_.release();
    vc_.open(fileName_);
    CV_Assert( vc_.isOpened() );
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Looks like the input video you specify in the arguments does not exist. But to know for sure you should check the code of frame_source.cpp and see what the assertion is about...

Comment: @diip_thomas ./SuperResolution -v /path/to/video.3gp that is what I write in terminal. I've edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you have a codec problem. The assertion checks if the source can be opened or not. When it fails it gives you the error you describe. It can fail because the source does not exist or because the it is unable to open the file format or read the codec. You can also try another .avi video to see if that does work. If it does, you can be pretty sure it is a codec problem.

See this SO post for some ways to check the codecs: [Why can't I open avi video in openCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414947/why-cant-i-open-avi-video-in-opencv)

You can check the codec of the file by opening a Linux terminal and typing:

`ffmpeg -i video.3gp`

Then you can see which libs are installed and what the video encoding is. For instance:

`Stream: #0.0: Video mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p, 1280x720, 30.02 tbr`

Shows that both FFMPEG is working correctly (otherwise you'd get an error message) and that the file is MJPG encoded.

Another option is that your openCV installation did not build with FFMPEG. You can check that by running cmake and check if cmake is detected. It should look like:

`--     FFMPEG:                      YES`

Apparently sometimes your FFMPEG can be installed and detected, but not configured properly. This SO post shows a solution: [VideoCapture is not working in OpenCV 2.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444926/videocapture-is-not-working-in-opencv-2-4-2/11465097#11465097)

Comment: With .avi the same thing

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64 bit

Comment: Yes, I ve checked it when you first answer this question. I followed link. ffmpeg works well

Comment: Can you open the same video in a simple OpenCV example?

Comment: video in simple example didn't opened.

Comment: That probably means that OpenCV is not able to load video, so not properly compiled for your system. See updated answer or try to make and install again and check the cmake settings for FFMPEG.

Comment: Today I ve compiled with 'cmake FFMPEG = ON'. But the same. Video cannot opened. I'm keep searching. Thank you for help. When something will be clear I'll inform

Comment: Okay! I did the same thing in Windows and video plays correctly however I haven't found workable way in Ubuntu

Comment: At least now we know it's an installation issue on Ubuntu, not in the code. I have added another link to my answer that might be useful